# Create diagnoal matrix from rows of a matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to create a diagonal matrix from rows of another matrix. E.g. if given matrix is:

```
 M=[e_1,e_2,e_3]
```

where $e_i$, i=1,2,3, is a vector. Now my output looks like this:

```
N = [e_1,0,0
      0, e_2,0
      0,0, e_3
    ]
```

Assume 0 in the above matrix are blocks of zeros of appropriate size.
Edit: output example
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
e_1 = np.array([1,2,3])
e_2 = np.array([4,5,6])
e_3 = np.array([7,8,9])

M = [e_1, e_2, e_3]

# output = np.hstack(np.eye(e_1.shape[0])[:,:,None] * M)
output = np.hstack(np.eye(len(M))[:,:,None] * M)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 5., 6., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 7., 8., 9.]])
```

Unpacked:

```
>>> np.eye(e_1.shape[0])

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])

>>> np.eye(e_1.shape[0])[..., None]

array([[[1.],
        [0.],
        [0.]],

       [[0.],
        [1.],
        [0.]],

       [[0.],
        [0.],
        [1.]]])
```

1. [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) concatenates arrays horizontally.
2. [`np.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) returns Identity matrix of given shape.
3. np.array()[..., None] adds another dimension to the array. This is equivalent to `np.newaxis` and can also be achieved by `np.expand_dims`.

edit: `len(M)` will ensure that number of rows in outputs are equal to number of input vectors.

Comment: above fails if `M = [e_1, e_2]`. i.e. `M` has just two  vectors; each of size 3.